# sqlite-pcl database initialization in android platform

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I have a very strange case using sqlite-pcl in android platform ... I have one class for database which is inherited from SQLiteConnection, I use personal folder for my db, in constructor I have one check for existence, but often when I start application again , without deleting any files, it return false...

```
 public class ScannifyDatabase : SQLiteConnection
            {
       public static string DBPath
                {
                    get
                    {
                        string path =        System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                        return System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Scaniff.db3");
                    }
                }
      public ScannifyDatabase(string path)
                : base(new SQLitePlatformAndroid(),path)
            {
                if (!TableExists())
                {
                 this.CreateTable<DocumentType>();
                 InitData();
                }
           }
       private bool TableExists()
            {
               // return this.TableExists();
                const string cmdText = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?";
                var cmd = this.CreateCommand(cmdText, typeof(DocumentType).Name);
                var res = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd.ExecuteScalar<string>());
                return res;
            }

 }
```

what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xamarin Studio, under Preferences --> Android, be sure that you have "Preserve data/cache between application deploys" checked.  There is a similar setting in Visual Studio.